# css single div, multiple effects

Tags: css, hover, effects

I'm trying to create a nice hover/click effect on my div.

I have a vertical item list (#textboxitem) inside of a container (#bgtextbox), separated by squares (#wwa_squares). When one of my items is hovered over, another div (image) appears in my live area box (#main_photo) behind the squares. When the item is clicked the image opacity changes and converts to grayscale, also a text field appears.

It is all CSS and works great... almost

My problem is that I can't figure out how to assign different images and text to appear when the other items are hovered/clicked. Right now only one image and sample text is applied to all items. The image appears behind the squares when item is hovered, but comes to the front when item is clicked. I would also like to have the image and text stay active when clicked.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

**CSS**

```
#bgtextbox{
    width:320px;
    height:490px;
    background-color:#BCBEC0;
    margin:130px 0 0 0px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

#textboxitem{
        width:340px;
        height:40px;
        background-color:#E6E7E8;
        margin:6px 0 0 0px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:40px;
        border:1px solid #E6E7E8;
        }

#textboxitem:hover{
            border:1px solid #F15A24;
            cursor:pointer;             
            }

#textboxitem:hover ~ #main_photo img{
                            opacity:1;                                      
                            }

#textboxitem:active ~ #main_photo img{  
                        filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        opacity:.5;
                        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

            }

#textboxitem:active ~ #main_photo_text{

                    background-color:#000;
                    color:#FFF;


            }


#main_photo{
        width:620px;
        height:490px;
        margin:-480px 0 0 370px;
        text-align:center;

        background-repeat:no-repeat;



        }

#main_photo img{
            opacity:0;
            max-height:100%;
            max-width:100%;
            } 

#main_photo_text{
            width:430px;
            height:150px;
            margin:-150px 0 0 397px;
            position:absolute;
            border-radius: 20px / 20px;
            opacity:.75;
            color:transparent;
            }




#wwa_ysquares{
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        background-color:#fdb813;
        position:absolute;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        transform: rotate(-65deg);
        margin:100px 0 0 -200px;
        border-radius: 50px / 50px;
        opacity: 0.75;
        }

#wwa_osquares{
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        background-color:#f15922;
        position:absolute;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        transform: rotate(-65deg);
        margin:380px 0 0 400px;
        border-radius: 50px / 50px;
        opacity: 0.75;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="bgtextbox">

<div id="wwa_ysquares"></div>

<div id="wwa_osquares"></div>
<div id="textboxitem">PRINT</div>
<div id="textboxitem">PACKAGING</div>
<div id="textboxitem">DISPLAYS</div>
<div id="textboxitem">SPECIALTY PACKAGING</div>
<div id="textboxitem">PACKAGING SUPPLIES</div>
<div id="textboxitem">PROTOTYPES/SAMPLES</div>
<div id="textboxitem">SUPPLIES</div>
<div id="textboxitem">FULLFILMENT/ASSEMBLY</div>
<div id="textboxitem">RSC AND CUSTOM CORRUGATED</div>
<div id="textboxitem">INDUSTRIAL</div>
<div id="main_photo"><img src="images/HYDRATION.jpg"</div></div>
<div id="main_photo_text">TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have more than 1 item with the same ID.

Comment: Hi @user, welcome to SO.  Per the comments above, I'd reommend class instead of id, but I'm not sure if that's a downvoteable offense ;).

Comment: so i would have to have multiple id's?

Comment: @Steve how would i go about using classes?

Comment: use html attribute like - `classs="textboxitem"` and in CSS like - `.textboxitem`

Comment: @Mr. Alien what would be a good solution, if any. I'm trying to avoid JS

Comment: @leech - That's not JS, it's CSS.  Your concept of `id` in your head is actually a `class`.  So instead of many `id='blah'` on a bunch of elements, it should be `class='blah'` on all of those elements.  This is because, like a driver's license, hopefully IDs are unique.  The page will work without them, but it's like naming all of your kids "Joe".  When you say "Come here, Joe" they'll all come running and you'll have trouble addressing just one of them.  Instead, give them classes.  Classes apply to groups, ids to individuals. You're trying to apply a style to a group, so use a class.

Comment: @steve - I figured it out, changed them all to classes. But the problem I am running into now is that when clicked the image and text doesn't stay visible. I am trying to :target them but I can't seem to make any progress.

Comment: I have my updated code here if you wouldn't mind taking a look.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824801/css-layering-and-active-class-issues/16826227?noredirect=1#comment24260145_16826227 @Steve