# css layering and active class issues

Tags: html, css

I created a hover/click effect on my class(es) and the effect I am going for works fine, but I want it to stay active when clicked, until a new item is selected. And I can't make the image(s) appear behind my squares.

I've tried changing the position on both my image container and the squares and nothing seems to work. Is there a way to layer in css? I know there is z-index but i don't understand that function.

**CSS**

```
#bgtextbox{
    width:320px;
    height:490px;
    background-color:#BCBEC0;
    margin:130px 0 0 0px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

#wwa_ysquares{
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        background-color:#fdb813;
        position:absolute;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        transform: rotate(-65deg);
        margin:100px 0 0 -200px;
        border-radius: 50px / 50px;
        opacity: 0.75;
        }

#wwa_osquares{
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        background-color:#f15922;
        position:absolute;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
        transform: rotate(-65deg);
        margin:380px 0 0 400px;
        border-radius: 50px / 50px;
        opacity: 0.75;
        }

/* hover/click START */
.print{
        width:340px;
        height:40px;
        background-color:#E6E7E8;
        margin:6px 0 0 0px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:40px;
        border:1px solid #E6E7E8;
        }

.print_photo{
        width:620px;
        height:490px;
        margin:-48px 0 0 370px;
        text-align:center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position:absolute;          
        }

.print_photo img{
            opacity:0;
            max-height:100%;
            max-width:100%;
            } 

.print_text{
            width:430px;
            height:150px;
            margin:292px 0 0 397px;
            position:absolute;
            border-radius: 20px / 20px;
            opacity:.75;
            color:transparent;
            }


.print:hover{
            border:1px solid #F15A24;
            cursor:pointer;             
            }

.print:hover ~ .print_photo img{
                            opacity:1;                                      
                            }

.print:active ~ .print_photo img{   
                        filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        opacity:.5;
                        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                        }

.print:active ~ .print_text{                            
                    background-color:#000;
                    color:#FFF;
                    }
    /* END */
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="bgtextbox">
<div id="wwa_ysquares"></div>
<div id="wwa_osquares"></div>
<div class="print">PRINT</div>
<div class="print_photo"><img src="images/print.png"</div></div>
<div class="print_text">PRINT TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't make something "stay active."  You can use an element that can receive focus (`button` perhaps) and use focus instead

Comment: @MattBerkowitz I'm a bit confused, can you elaborate more? or give me an example?

Comment: You would need to bring JS into the mix, adding a class or inline style that keeps the element visible until another action is taken. z-index allows you to layer one element above another, but z-index will only work on a positioned element (e.g. `position: absolute;` or `position: relative`).

Comment: JS scares me. I do not understand it.. Would it be possible to use the z-index in my situation? I have 8 different classes the same style as .print and I would like all of them to appear behind the squares. @ralph.m

Comment: z-index won't keep the element showing when not hovered, that's the problem. CSS can't do that alone. The only thing I can think of might be the :target pseudo selector.

Comment: @ralph.m     so i CAN position the image behind the squares with z-index?  that is my main goal. i can deal with the user holding the click down but if i have to use JS for the image to stay that is fine i'll try to figure it out. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of layering, as long as an element has position set (like `position: absolute` or `position: relative`) you can set a z-index to establish the layering order. The element with the highest z-index will sit on top. So the `wwa_ysquares` div will sit above the `print_photo` if the former is given a higher z-index.

(There are gotchas with z-index, such as if you are setting the z-index on inner elements ... but that's not an issue here.)

Comment: so would i make the squares z-index 9 & 10, and then move down the line for my photos? or would i have to apply it to each div class i have?

Comment: You only need to add it to any div that you want layered over/under another. You can set any number, too, like `z-index: 100`, so don't be afraid to use larger numbers in case you'll need to add other elements in between later on.

Comment: hey ralph can you elaborate a little bit on the :target pseudo?
would I replace :active with it? and instead of a <div would i just use <a href?

Comment: No, target is a special selector that goes on the element that is targeted by a link. Here's an example of it in action: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/pyfsq

Comment: Won't that cancel my hover effect?

Comment: It has nothing to do with hover, which works independently. But I'm not really clear on what you are attempting. If you post a working example, and make it clear what you want it to do, I'll help you integrate it.

Comment: The code I have on my question works in google chrome and firefox,  you would just have to replace the image in the html to see the effect in action. The effect works, I would just like it to keep the active state appearance once clicked.

Comment: `you would just have to replace the image` ... It's dangerous to tell people trying to help you that they have to do the work. :-) What are the dimensions of the image? `I would just like it so keep the active appearance once clicked` That's a perfect job for :target. But using your code, I don't really understand what you are trying to do with it, which is why a working example (with the image etc.) would make it easier to help.

Comment: Im sorry if that came off as demanding. I didn't know I could upload my images with the code. The image size is.    width:620px;    height:490px;

Comment: I just tried uploading the image but it says that I don't have enough reputation to upload images.